# Specifying only getter generates warning b/c no setter, but setter won't compile

Tags: ios, objective-c

I believe the image is pretty descriptive of my problem. If I define only a custom `getter` as below:

```
- (UIImage *) secondaryIconImage {   
    if (_secondaryIconImage) return _secondaryIconImage;
    return nil;
}
```

then I get an error: '`cannot pair a synthesized setter with a user defined getter`'. However, if I try to declare the `setter` as well my code won't compile at all:

```
- (void) setSecondaryIconImage:(UIImage *)secondaryIconImageVar {
    _secondaryIconImage = secondaryIconImageVar;
}
```

In particular this gives me the compile time error '`Use of undeclared identifier _secondaryIconImage`'

I thought perhaps once I declared the setter I would have to synthesize the instance variable myself, so I tried adding:

```
@synthesize _secondaryIconImage;
```

This didn't help. What's going on here and how can I fix it?

*p.s. I have a custom getter because I will eventually need to do something fancier, but I didn't see a reason to complicate the example since even this basic example is giving me a problem.*

Comment: Why do you need that setter?  That's exactly what the built in one would do...  Your compilation error is due to the fact you don't have a `_secondaryIconImage` variable defined in your class.  If you define that then everything should compile fine for you.

Comment: @Putz1103 I want to do more, just didn't see a reason to include that in the code.

Answer (score 2):

As it notes, you cannot define the getter without the setter. (Your getter makes no sense of course, so I assume your actual getter is more complex?)

If you define the getter and the setter, nothing will be synthesized for you (since you've written everything, there's nothing to synthesize), and no ivar will be defined for you. You need to define it yourself if you need it.

You need to explicitly request an ivar via your `@synthesize` (thanks to Richard Ross for setting me straight):

```
@synthesize secondaryIconImage = _secondaryIconImage;
```

Your code asks for a *property* called `_secondaryIconImage`, so the ivar would be `__secondaryIconImage`.

Comment: The second form (`@synthesize secondaryIconImage = _secondaryIconImage`) is the correct form. The first form is a no-op, as `@synthesize` without an associated name does not generate an iVar for legacy compatibility reasons.